# Результат множественного геокодирования

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Всем доброго времени суток. 
Есть список (50К записей), состоящий из адреса, города, области, названия организации, банковских реквизитов.
Задача состоит в получении координат. Т.е. "адрес", "город", "область", "название организации", "банковские реквизиты", "**Координаты**". Проблема в том, что не все адреса корректны.Из 50К где то 16К нормальные, остальные с ошибкой. Сделал через MultiGeocoder. Возвращает только адреса с координатами. Как можно прикрутить координаты к моему списку? Или как сделать, чтобы геокодер вернул мой список (который я ему посылаю)+координаты?
Просто я так понимаю, что входным параметром геокодера является весь массив адресов, а результатом result(адрес+координаты) и error.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что результаты геокодирования должны отображаться на общедоступной карте и их нельзя сохранять к себе в БД (геокодирование должно происходить в момент запроса с клиента). Нельзя просто спарсить координаты через Геокодер и сохранить себе - это будет нарушением условий использования и приведет к блокировке.

Comment: Учтено! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос можно закрывать.
Решение внезапно обнаружил тут:
https://cache-mskm902.cdn.yandex.net/download.cdn.yandex.net/tech/ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/examples/index.js

Только добавьте res.**result**.features.forEach......